# Display time in seconds within a loop

Tags: python, loops, time

I would like to create a while loop which prints time in seconds. The problem seems to be that the value for seconds keeps printing the same value over and over. This value is when the loop is enacted. I basically want the loop to count seconds without using sec = sec + 1.

```
import time

t = time.gmtime()

def display_seconds(x):
    sec = time.strftime('%S',x)
    sec = int(sec)
    print sec

while True:
    display_seconds(t)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is you are getting the time once, and then displaying the same time over and over again - notice that `t` never changes in your loop. Try this, instead:

```
import time

def display_seconds(x):
    sec = time.strftime('%S',x)
    sec = int(sec)
    print sec

while True:
    t = time.gmtime()
    display_seconds(t)
```

Comment: Not only did it work, it makes logical sense. I am not really needing to display something as elementary as time in seconds; however, it is a dynamically changing value which I can use to test my logic in order to apply it to another problem. I will accept this answer when stackoverflow allows me to do so. Thank you!

Comment: @branch.lizard: sure. make a `get_seconds` method which is the same as `display_seconds` except it returns `sec` instead of printing it. then do `if get_seconds(t) == 45: break`

Comment: Awesomeness!!! Thanks again. BTW, was un-accepting the answer the proper format to ask an additonal question about the OP the correct way of doing things on stackoverflow?

Comment: @branch.lizard: hmm not really, because the initial question was asked. usually it's enough to just comment on the answer and either the answerer or someone else will help you out. if not then you can ask another question

Comment: @branch.lizard: glad to be of help =)